Prefix increament in while loop
Node.js REPL
let i = 0;
while(i < 10){
    console.log(i);
    ++i;
}

The ouput of the above code block prints 10 along with numbers from 0 to 9. Why the following behaviour?
(Sorry for any grammatical mistakes, English is not first language)
I was expecting the output to be from 0 to 9.

If you put that code in a file and run it with Node, does it behave the same way?

The 10 isn't printed by the console.log but by the repl which always prints the result of the last expression, which is ++i in your case.

^^ Here's one way to tell @tkausl's correct: https://i.sstatic.net/tcsFU.png This is one of many reasons REPLs are poor environments for learning things about the language. REPLs do several things that can be confusing, not just printing things without your explicitly asking for them, but doing unusual things with scope, etc., which can be really confusing. Use real files run in the normal way to explore, not REPLs (or at least to verify).

Almost exactly the same question was asked a couple hours ago (closed). Plenty of explanation was provided there. Don't use the REPL until you are familiar with how it behaves. Put your code in a file and run it.
